# Vb.Net/SSIS Script Task - Handling null values

Tags: vb.net, ssis

Please see below code (issue with handling null values)

```
Dts.Variables("File_Name").Value = Framework.GetValue("FileName")
Dts.Variables("File_Id").Value = Framework.GetValue("FileName")

Dts.Variables("File_Name").Value - Data type defined in STRING
Dts.Variables("File_Id").Value - Data type defined in INTEGER
```

`Framework.GetValue` - Returns `STRING` (fetches value stored in database)

Problem - when Framework.GetValue returns nothing because value doesn't exist in database, it throws error in SSIS Script component. How to capture `NULL` is the problem we are facing

Public Function GetValue(ByVal FetchParameter As String) As String

```
Dim lGetValue As String = String.Empty

Using Conn New SqlConnection(ConnString)
    SQLCommand = New SqlCommand("ParameterValues", _ETLFrameworkConn)
    SQLCommand.CommandText = "Select ParamValue from ParameterValues where Parameter_Name=@ParameterField"
    SQLCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ParameterField").Value SqlDbType.NVarChar))
    SQLCommand.Parameters("@ParameterField").Value = FetchParameter 
    Try
        Conn.Open()
        lGetValue = SQLCommand.ExecuteScalar()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Using

Return lGetValue
```

End Function

Regards

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Can you post code in your method GetValue()? I think you need to check value to DBNULL.value before you return.

Comment: I have added the code can you please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code snippet in you GetValue() function. Added the DBNULL handling into the code. If there is no value String.Empty will be written.

```
Dim lGetValue As String = String.Empty

Using Conn New SqlConnection(ConnString)
    SQLCommand = New SqlCommand("ParameterValues", _ETLFrameworkConn)
    SQLCommand.CommandText = "Select ParamValue from ParameterValues where Parameter_Name=@ParameterField"
    SQLCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ParameterField").Value SqlDbType.NVarChar))
    SQLCommand.Parameters("@ParameterField").Value = FetchParameter 
    Try
        Conn.Open()
        var retrunVal = (string)SQLCommand.ExecuteScalar()

        IF returnVal = DBNULL.Value Then
            lGetValue = returnVal
        End

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Using

Return lGetValue
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What is the type of returnVal

Comment: also can you advice, when the value is passed from this function is assigned to INTEGER type in SSIS it gives me error. How can I cast?

Comment: From the code what I understood is that method returns String. SSIS will throw the error. You should be aware of the datatype.What data type your expecting from the GetValue() method?

Comment: what is the type of returnVal?

Comment: ExecuteScalar() returns will return the object. Modified the code to typecast the value to string.